# Table and Figure numbers with captions in Rstudio with knitr

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio

In previous iterations of knitr and Rstudio, figure captions with [automatic numbering were not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848137/figure-captions-references-using-knitr-and-markdown-to-html). But in the [newer Rmarkdown it seems they are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572188/captions-on-tables-in-pdf-documents-generated-by-rmarkdown). Robert Flight had a [nice solution](http://rmflight.github.io/posts/2012/10/papersinRmd.html) which I used before, but I'm wondering if there's a tidier way to do it in the new Rmarkdown. Is there?

Here's as far as I could get with my attempt. Captions are below not above the figures and no numbers are automatically generated.

````
---
title: "Test for caption"
output: 
  word_document:
    fig_caption: true
---


```{r, fig.cap='oh caption my caption', echo=FALSE} 
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, Petal.Length, color=Species)) + geom_point()
```
````

Session info:

```
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] markdown_0.7.4   rmarkdown_0.2.46

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.4    htmltools_0.2.4 tools_3.1.0
```

Comment: Please attach `library(rmarkdown); sessionInfo()`

Comment: Thanks @Yihui I've added this. Thanks for the ever-useful knitr!

Comment: Please paste the full sessionInfo() next time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using an old version of **rmarkdown**, please try to [upgrade it](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown) (to >= v0.2.65).