# How to change table captions for knitr sql chunks?

Tags: r, knitr

Here is a knitr chunk that connects to a database and a sql chunk that runs a query on the database:

````
```{r dbConnect}
con <- RMySQL::dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname = "test")
```

```{sql rowsintable, connection=con}
select count(*) from tablename;
```
````

I use this document to generate a PDF file. In the pdf document, the table returned by the sql chunk has a caption: "Table 1: 1 records".
How can I change this caption?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572188/captions-on-tables-in-pdf-documents-generated-by-rmarkdown) is related, but doesn't use SQL chunks, and it sets the caption inside an R function, not in the knitr [chunk options](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the chunk option `tab.cap`, e.g.

````
```{r dbConnect}
con <- RMySQL::dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname = "test")
```

```{sql rowsintable, connection=con, tab.cap="Here is the caption."}
select count(*) from tablename;
```
````